# Binding a TextBlock to a Property a ListView changes

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, properties, observer-pattern

I just can't figure it out. What I am missing to bound the `Textblock`?
I need the `TextBlock` to update everytime I select a new item in the `ListView`.

This is a sample I made. I my real application, I used the id from the ListView1 to fetch something from my DB that I want to display in my textBlock..

I know WPF binds to Properties and I need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` but I can't get the bindings right or maybe I am missing something else?

I have added `DateTime.Now.TosString()` just to see more clearly if the `TextBlock` changes.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfSO.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txtBlockPerson" 
                                Text="{Binding MyPerson}" />


        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="ListView1" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ListData}" 
                  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" 
                  SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">

            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfSO
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Person> ListData { get; set; }
        private const string _myName = "You clicked on: ";
        public Person MyPerson { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // TextBlock
            MyPerson = new Person(_myName);
            txtBlockPerson.DataContext = MyPerson;

            // ListView
            ListData = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
            var p1 = new Person("p1");
            var p2 = new Person("p2");
            ListData.Add(p1);
            ListData.Add(p2);

            ListView1.ItemsSource = ListData;
        }

        private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MyPerson.Name = _myName + ListView1.SelectedItem + ". Time: " +DateTime.Now.ToString(); 
        }
    }

    public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != _name)
                {
                    _name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
                }
            }
        }

        public Person(string name)
        {
            Name = name;
        }

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event 
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OnPropertyChanged needs to have the correct name of your property..

Instead of `OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");` use

```
OnPropertyChanged("Name");
```

Comment: +1 wow thanks, I didn't knew. Oh I see it has to have the "name" as the Property. First test looks like it works. I'll accept after some more testing.